# How to trigger a function when the ion-menu-button is closed in ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic4

How to trigger a function when the ion-menu-button is closed in ionic.
I have a ion-menu-button like this

```
<ion-buttons slot="end"   >
  <ion-menu-button menu="admin"  >
    <ion-icon name="more" ></ion-icon>
  </ion-menu-button>
</ion-buttons>
```

Please help me by telling how to trigger a function when the ion-menu-button is closed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fhefa.jpg. This is the menu list

Comment: Which function you want to trigger and when?

Comment: I want to just trigger a user-defined-function and that too on the close of ion-button.Something like logging to console saying menu close.Actually my purpose is to retrive an id and stored in localstorage when the menu closes

Comment: You can either use (ionWillClose)="some method" or (ionDidClose)="some method"

Comment: @Mostafa Harb I tried that but it is not working'

Comment: I have shown an image when i click the name in the list the ion-menu close.But nothing is logged in console

Comment: Ok , then you have to add menu controller in the page you need, and subscript to ionDidClose from code not from html.

Comment: Mostafa can you please give me some code reference to do that

Answer (score 1):

That is because `ion-menu-button` does not emit any event whatsoever, it is merely a controller so it doesn't even make sense for it to emit anything. You can either attach ionDidClose / ionWillClose events to the `ion-menu` instance itself or subscribe to `MenuController`. One really hacky way to achieve what you need (if you really really need to attach the event to the button itself) would be using `(click)` event.

If you need more information, head over to Ionic documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/app/MenuController/ and (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu#events.

Comment: Jiri Kraloevec .Can you please give me a code snippet which shows how to attach ionDidClose on the ion-menu

Comment: I want to retrieve an id from menu as shown in figure when the slider closes on clicking lists.

Comment: In that case, you can have a callback function opening a specific menu via the MenuController (`MenuController.open([id])`). Sorry, I can't provide you with an example atm..